# Django InconsistentMigrationHistory with fresh restore

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

- I am having trouble with migrations from this new dump that I received from my test server.
- This is the error that I am getting in the terminal after I execute the command `python manage.py migrate`.

```py
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration rmas.0001_initial is applied before its dependency equipment.0002_auto_20210629_1540 on database 'default'.
```

I have been looking through some of the other related questions in StackOverflow and I have done about every suggestion including:

- drop the database
- delete django_migrations
- comment out admin in urls.py
- make sure that AUTH_USER_MODEL is in the .py files for dependency issues

```py
migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

This is after running the command `python manage.py showmigrations` and you can see that it is just this one file that is causing a whole lot of issues.

```py
equipment
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20210629_1540
guardian
 [X] 0001_initial
inspections
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20210629_1540
notifications
 [X] 0001_initial
pendingsrns
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_pendingsrn_verified_srn
product_support
 (no migrations)
repairs
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_auto_20210629_1540
reversion
 [X] 0001_initial
rmas
 [X] 0001_initial
```

For context if you need it:

- Django version = 1.11.24
- Python version = 2.7
- PostgreSQL 12

Please let me know if you need any additional information in order to make sense of this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have handwritten migrations?

Comment: I'm not quite sure? I am pretty new to Django and migrations. I know that we have a django_migrations table that is what I clear out when I go to redo the migrations. How do I find out that answer for you?

Comment: Ok, so `rmas.0001_initial` has been applied, and `equipment.0002_auto_20210629_1540` hasn't, but the `equipment` migration depends on the `rmas` migration. You could change the dependency in `equipment` so that the value for the `rmas` dependency is just `__latest__`